# Find the value of $\sqrt[4]{\alpha}-\sqrt[4]{\beta}$,where $\sqrt[4]{.}$ denotes the principal value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-34x+1=0$,find the value of $\sqrt[4]{\alpha}-\sqrt[4]{\beta}$,where $\sqrt[4]{.}$ denotes the principal value.

---

I found out the $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
$\alpha,\beta=\frac{34\pm\sqrt{32\times 36}}{2}=17\pm12\sqrt2$ but i do not know how to find $\sqrt[4]{\alpha}-\sqrt[4]{\beta}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
(\sqrt{2}-1)^2=3-2\sqrt{2}
$$ and that
$$
(3-2\sqrt{2})^2=17-12\sqrt{2}
$$ thus
$$
(\sqrt{2}-1)^4=17-12\sqrt{2}
$$ giving

> $$
> \sqrt[4]{\alpha}=\sqrt[4]{17-12\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}-1,
> $$

similarly

> $$
> \sqrt[4]{\beta}=\sqrt[4]{17+12\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}+1.
> $$

Comment: Yes, "one may observer that" if one knows a little bit about Pell's equation and recognizes a good approximation to $\sqrt{2}$. I was about to post a similar answer, as a big hint, adding a hope that someone else can provide an answer at a precalculus level.

Comment: Brilliant Olivier,how does it click to you to take $\sqrt2-1$@Olivier Oloa

Comment: @Brahmagupta Thank you. This answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695381/how-to-simplify-the-nested-radical-sqrt1-frac-sqrt32-by-hand/1695382#1695382 helped me:)

Answer (score 3):

From the properties of the roots of a quadratic equation we can deduce that:$$\alpha+\beta=34\tag{1}$$$$\alpha\beta=1\tag{2}$$Next we see that:$$(\sqrt[4]{\alpha}-\sqrt[4]{\beta})^2=\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\beta}-2\sqrt[4]{\alpha\beta}=\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\beta}-2\text{ (using (2) above)}\tag{3}$$We also see that:$$(\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\beta})^2=\alpha+\beta+2\sqrt{\alpha\beta}=34+2\text{ (using (1) and (2) above)}$$$$\therefore\sqrt{\alpha}+\sqrt{\beta}=\sqrt{36}=6$$Now substitute this into (3) and hopefully you can finish this off.